# Android swipebutton centerposition

Tags: java, android, button, swipe, user-experience

I followed this tutorial: https://android.jlelse.eu/make-a-great-android-ux-how-to-make-a-swipe-button-eefbf060326d

It gave me a lot of information about swipebuttons, and I almost got it to work in my project. I need to swipe both left and right, and therefore I need the round slidingbutton to start in the middle instead of at the left side.

I can make it return to the middle with a function, but I can't seem to find a place where I set some initial positions of it.

**EDIT:**

XML in the layout:

```
<com.example.frederik.promille.SwipeButtonBeer
android:id="@+id/swipe_btn_beer"
android:layout_width="340dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />
```

Code to return the button to the middle:

```
public void moveButtonBack() {
        final ValueAnimator positionAnimator =
                ValueAnimator.ofFloat(slidingButton.getX(), (getWidth()-initialButtonWidth)/2);
        positionAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        positionAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                float x = (Float) positionAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                slidingButton.setX(x);
            }
        });

        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                centerText, "alpha", 1);

        positionAnimator.setDuration(200);

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimator, positionAnimator);
        animatorSet.start();
    }
```

Comment: Please add your layout XML and the function you wrote to return it to the middle.

Comment: @Dinei I've updated my question.